# Is there a way I can make the input to act like "display: inline-block"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

What I am trying to do is implement a simple inline editing, I'm using a normal div to display the text when the edit state is false, and render an input when the edit state is true.

The problem I'm facing is that the input doesn't wrap around the text content it's got, like a div with `display: inline-block` would. I tried setting the `size` attribute of the input to be that of the current value's length, but it's not wrapping around the content perfectly.

Any ideas how to do it? I guess `contentEditable` on the span itself, without an input, is an option, but I want to be able to select all the content in the input when it gets the focus.

Here is the code.

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("test");
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.select();
  }, [active]);

  const length = value.split(" ").join("").length;

  return (
    <>
      {!active && <span onClick={() => setActive(true)}>{value}</span>}
      {active && (
        <input
          value={value}
          size={length}
          ref={ref}
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          onBlur={() => setActive(false)}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: `<input>` element is by default inline-block. What exactly are you trying to convey.

Comment: Input does not support text wrapping, consider using textarea? If you want to filter some characters, such as \n, you can use RegExp to filter in onChange.

Comment: @Garfield550 I tried textarea, but it seems to have a default size too?

Comment: @kristalshards You can use css width/hight properties styling textarea. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#styling_with_css